# Unit testing and data returned from the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am using EF 6.1 and I will be handling the CUD in CRUD [using this pattern.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488264/Unit-testing-made-easy-Part-Repository-Testing) I am trying to decide what the best way to handle R(etrieve) is.  Lets say my repository method returns a collection:

```
 public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.MyObject.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    }
```

Should I be creating a test object that looks exactly like what the database will return?
if yes, What if the database returns a list of over 200 items?

Should I assert that one or two items exist in the collection and move on?

Is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: What are you trying to test? The GetAll() method?

Comment: @Mark I would venture to say I should test that the data I get back is correct; however, that seems like I am testing what EF does and that seems silly

Comment: Will this be a unit test or an integration test?

Comment: This is the Unit Test. I will be doing Integration tests after that walk the entire chain

Comment: @Robert Like you said before: Its rather silly testing this particular  piece of code, as you'd be testing functionality you did not write. Microsoft did.

Comment: @Robert for a unit test, the only thing you should be testing in this method which has a single line of code, is to Assert that when the GetAll() method is called, a single call is made to the _context.MyObject.OrderBy() method and nothing else.

Comment: @hSchroedl So it would be better to skip the Unit testing here and go straight to an integration test?

Comment: @Mark I was thinking that as well. I will mock my context object and just jump into integration tests.

Comment: @Robert not sure I entirely agree that it's silly to write a unit test for this method as you won't be testing Microsoft's code. We will only verify that our code does in fact call _context.MyObject.OrderBy(). It'll be a very simple 3 line unit test but well worth having.

Comment: @Mark Sorry I wasn't clear on that. I meant in the Unit tests I will mock my Context object and verify called methods. After I verify those methods were called then I will move on to integration tests.

Comment: @Robert by the way, you don't need to mock anything to write Integration Tests. Your integration test should hit the real database. EDIT: this comment can be ignored after your response

Comment: @Mark: an integration test should hit *a* database but I wouldn't recommend you to use your production database.

Comment: @Jereon Vannevel couldn't agree more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can mock object of _context and from that get the items

Comment: If I was to mock the object, what would I be testing at that point. I know EF works behind the scenes.

Comment: You would be testing the code inside your repository: the LINQ queries.